# Need Javascript If the Sequence match the Html Structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

Javascript expert this is my template coding:

```
<html>

<head>        
</head>

<body>

<div id='top'>
  <h2> This is my website headline </h2>
</div>


<div class='outer-wrapper'>
  <h3>This is content area for main blog </h3>
 </div>


<div class='footer'>
  <h4> This is footer content area </h4>
</div>


<!--Copyright Structure Start-->

<div id='copyright'>
  <div id='container'>
    <p>Copyright 2016. Designed By <a href='#'>Company</a> 
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>  

 <!--Copyright Structure End-->


</body>
</html>
```

i have the below html structure that is used in the template.

```
<div id='copyright'>
  <div id='container'>
    <p> Designed By <a id='doom' href='http://www.example.com'>Company</a> 
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Case 1:** Now,i want if the same sequence exist **#copyright > #container > p > a#doom** in the the html structure inside the template Then its ok, if any if these has removed, then redirect my page to example.com.

```
   <div id='copyright'>
      <div id='container'>   
        </div>
      </div>
```

See the structure above has no **`<p></P>`** tag, now it should be redirected.

**Case 2:** If there is added extra other html tag inside my html structure in the template rather than these tags: **#copyright #container P and a#doom**. then it should also redirected.

```
<div id='copyright'>
  <div id='container'>
  <div id='wrap'>
    <p> Designed By <a id='doom' href='http://www.example.com'>Company</a> 
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the structure has extra **div wrap** now, it should redirected to example.com because it does not match the sequence.

I hope someone will give the script soon. thanks.

Comment: "Then its ok, if any if these has removed, then redirect my page to example.com." - Can you clarify?

Comment: @Hybrid yes, and if added another tag inside that html structure then it should also redirected as you see in Case 2: we added div wrap now it should be redirected if someone add extra html tag inside the html structure.

Comment: at which point of code execution these validation should come into picture. For example; is there a submit or validate button on your page you want the DOM should get validate? or which is that trigger point?

Comment: @vijayP i have updated the code and more clarification please read again. thanks.

Comment: how you are embedding your template HTML into the DOM? Are you using any framework/template engine for this?

Comment: @JohanKarlsson please you check this post and if possible share the code. thanks.

Comment: Not @vijayp this is just a simple html page that is created in html and css.

Comment: Please try the solution provided by MasNotsram. You will need to incorporate `jquery` onto your page to use that solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the selector in JQuery and check the length. If you change the HTML, the selector won't match, and you don't redirect:

Run this when you HTML **has loaded** (onLoad or domReady):

```
if( $('#copyright > #container > p > a#doom').length == 0 ) {
    alert("Redirect");
}
```

**Example fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/feb5zex2/

Comment: hi, @MasNotsram your code is worked if any of that html tag removed from the html structure... however, there is still something missing, i add extra div in that html structure then it is not redirecting...as what i told in Case 2 above. you can see it here live: https://jsfiddle.net/feb5zex2/5/

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to run this code when the document is ready (1. line) and if a specific CSS selector with direct ancestor combinations doesn't match (2. line), redirect using window.location.replace() (3. line).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#copyright > #container > p > a#doom").length == 0) {
        window.location.replace("http://www.example.com");
    }
})
```

Comment: your code worked perfect is missing any tag in that html structure, however it does not work, if i add extra div in the html structure...check here: https://jsfiddle.net/feb5zex2/5/

Comment: Right. The selector above checks that the chain of elements is existent. It doesn't check whether there's other extra elements alongside that hierarchy. Looks like you rather want to compare the whole HTML inside #copyright. On the other hand, really, is that necessary? You can't effectively force people to keep your copyright note other than trusting them and checking from time to time yourself. If this is a commercial WP theme or the like I'd rather check if your company name and/or link exists anywhere on the page. But even then, people always can edit your JS.

Comment: yes you understand it...buddy is there any script which check the whole #copyright structure,  if it is the same, as i shared above then its ok, but if there is added any html tag inside #copyright then redirect the page..thanks.

Comment: You can always get the whole html using $("#copyright").html() and compare it to a hardcoded piece of htm, but are you sure you want this? And do you have the sovereignty of the JS? If you give a customer a template with this JS included he can simply delete the piece of JS.